# How to replace all substrings?

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to replace all the text within brackets to uppercase letters for any `String` object. For example if the text is - `Hi (abc), how (a)re (You)?"` , output should be - `Hi ABC, how Are YOU?` . I tried to use `StringUtils.SubstringBetween()`, but that replaces only the first substring between `()`.
Using `regex`, I suppose the `group()` method requires the count of such substrings. What is the correct direction to be taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java 9 we can use [`Matcher.replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-)

```
String str = "Hi (abc), how (a)re (You)?";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)"); //matches parenthesis and places 
                                            //content between them in group 1
String replaced = p.matcher(str)
        .replaceAll(match -> match.group(1).toUpperCase()); //replace each match with
                                            //content of its group 1 in its upper case 

System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output: `Hi ABC, how Are YOU?`